# How to redirect outgoing traffic of a pod using Istio

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have an application that I have containerized and running inside of a Kubernetes cluster. The application is running on port 8443 however there is a bug within the application that I have no control over and it sends requests to itself at port 80. As a workaround I would like to redirect any traffic destined for http://myapp.com:80 to instead go to http://myapp.com:8443. I also need mTLS.

I tried using a service entry which worked to redirect the traffic, but it did not use mTLS.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: interal-svc-redirect
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  hosts:
  - myapp.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
  endpoints:
  - address: mynamespace.myapp.svc.cluster.local
    ports:
      http: 8443
```